# How to solve $x+\sqrt{1+x^2}=3\sqrt{3}$ for $x$?

Tags: problem-solving

How do I solve the following equation for x:

$x+\sqrt{1+x^2}=3\sqrt{3}$

I'm failing miserably in isolating the $x$

Comment: Start by getting that square root by itself:

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Isolate $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ on one side of the equation and then square both sides

Comment: So simple when you see it... I've tried everything except the right one!

Comment: Note that if you are squaring equations to solve them you need to take care. $x=a$ has one solution, but $x^2=a^2$ has two. So you do need here to show in some way that the value you obtain solves the original equation. It isn't difficult here, but in more complex questions, don't let it trip you up. (here the second solution disappears - informally, we might say to $x=-\infty$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing your equation in the form

$$\sqrt{1+x^2}=3\sqrt{3}-x$$ and by squaring we get
$$1+x^2=27+x^2-6\sqrt{3}x$$ so we get
$$6\sqrt{3}x=26$$
Can you finish?

Comment: I surely can. So simple after seeing it that is embarassing.

Answer (score 1):

Hint $$(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x)(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x)=1$$

$$\implies\sqrt{1+x^2}-x=\dfrac1{3\sqrt3}$$

Can you take it from here?